# Laravel 5.4 Artisan Migrate fails with Call to undefined method dispatch()

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel 5.4 app that works fine locally. In trying to put it on my production server, I cannot run migrations. Here is part of the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::dispatch() in /path/to/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:56
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
I just tried to run `php artisan --help` and, I get the same error.

Comment: You can not use migrations, so did you use --pretend to update DB structure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete all files from `/bootstrap/cache/` and run these commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

It should fix your problem

Comment: @RogerCreasy And you have deleted /bootstrap/cache ?

Comment: Ugh...sorry. rushing to try and fix...didn't read completely. Will in a sec

Comment: Now, both of those give an error that laravel.log cannot be opened

Comment: But....for s & g I tried running the migrations, they worked! Is anything else broken now with the deletions?

Comment: @RogerCreasy This is only cache and shouldn't break anything else

Answer (score 2):

I think your composer is not updated. Try uninstalling the composer and then re-installing it. Or try with updating the composer.phar. Probably there is version issue between the laravel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Running "composer update" solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by:

1. connected to my production server.
2. cd bootstrap/cache and removed `compiled.php`file by running `rm compiled.php` command.